# Import classes/functions from Python files saved in same folder showing "No Module Named" error

Tags: python

As per screen print, `import` shows error in `Python 3.7` version, earlier it was working fine in version `Python 2.7` and I am using **IntelliJ Idea**.

If you see, EOC related .py files are in the same folder and have classes which are being called in *Main_EOC.py* by passing objects which are inter-related. It's amazing to see the red line while importing files from same folder.

Please help me why it's showing such error

> "This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.`"

Also, if you see the line which have full path, is not showing error

```
from EOC_Module.eoc.script.config import Config
```

Please help me if there is a way to add this full path on top of the code or other option.

[image]

Comment: Besides things not working from python 2.7 to 3.6 there is no other real reason this wouldn't work. Have you tried to restart your IDE at all? If so, insure the files are in the correct locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of import path search changed between python2 and python3. The import path always includes the directory from which the `main` module was loaded, but it no longer includes directories from which modules were imported.

You need to change your import statement syntax as follows, if you want to import a module that lives in the same directory as the module in which you do the import:

```
# old way, import works if the named module is in this module's directory
import x

# new (Python3) way:
from . import x
```

For the second part: adding a path so all code can import from a certain directory: if that directory is (and will always be) **relative** to your `main`: you can add a few lines in the main module to make it available. Something like this:

```
import sys # if you haven't imported it already
import os.path

home = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
sys.path.append( os.path.join(home, "EOC_Module/eoc/script") )

# now, you can import straight from the script directory
import EOC_Intraction
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. It removes red lines now but showing error -- ImportError: cannot import name 'Eoc_Summary' from '__main__' (C:/EOC_Module/EOC_Module/eoc/script/Main_EOC.py)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But all imports showing same red lines with same errors.

Comment: The 'red lines' are likely due to a code analyzer built into the IDE editor that you are using. The method of resolving it that I suggested (modifying `sys.path` at run time) works to allow the modules to be imported, but it cannot be 'seen' by the code analyzer (the path change happens only when you run the code and the analyzer won't do that). If the code works as you want it and it is convenient for you to use short names for the modules rather than `from very.long.path include x`, you can safely ignore the squiggly red lines.

Comment: Hi Leo, I really thank you for the solution and quick reply. This works now.

Answer (score 0):

When using pycharm the root directory for your python executable is the same as the root directory of your project, this means that python will start looking for files in the root directory with this files:

.idea/
EOC_module/
logs/
reports/
sql/

This is the reason of why: `from EOC_Module.eoc.script.config import Config` works.

If you execute your code from the terminal with: `python3 Main_EOC.py` (not pycharm) the root directory for your python will be the same as the one containing the file, all the other imports will work but `from EOC_Module.eoc.script.config import Config` not.

So you need to make your imports from project directory if you are using pycharm.

Comment: Hi Jaime, Thank you for the reply. So, I have changed all imports into -- "from EOC_Module.eoc.script import xxx". It works. But is this the best solution, repeating same in each import? What could be the best approach? Might be my project coding style is not appropriate.

Comment: If you were to run your executables through pycharm "run" button you need to use the full names (but the main.py wouldnt work if you execute from terminal). If i had to choose I would go with coding in any IDE as pycharm or code editor( ATOM,VSCODE) and execute in terminal, this will allow you to use the short imports and an easier portability when replicating results as people wil probably just run main.py.